# Chrome Not Caching HTTP 301 Redirect

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, http-status-code-301

I'm working on dynamic HTTP 301 Redirect responses for an ASP.Net project, and they are cached correctly in Firefox, but no matter what I set the cache headers to, the redirect is never cached by Chrome:

**Headers**
**General:**

Request URL:https://*domain*/old/spot

Request Method:GET

Status Code:301

Remote Address:127.0.0.1:443

Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

**Response Headers:**

**cache-control:private, max-age=3600**

content-length:0

content-type:text/html

date:Fri, 27 Oct 2017 **14:03:28** GMT

expires:Fri, 27 Oct 2017 **15:03:28** GMT

location:/blog1/test

server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0

status:301

**Request Headers:**

:authority:*domain*

:method:GET

:path:/old/spot

:scheme:https

user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36

Comment: Do you have dev tools open? And do you have the "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)" setting enabled? Or "Disable cache" on the network tab? I believe both of these prevent 301s being cached.

Comment: @Turnip both of those are unchecked (disabled) to allow caching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With self-signed SSL certificates, Chrome ignores all caching directives and reloads the content ... This is a known issue with Chrome browser.  It does not cache responses if the HTTPS connection is using an invalid Certificate.  See this bug report for details:
>   https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=110649#c8

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/cache-problems-on-chrome-with-SSL-certificate-errors.html

We're going to work around by testing with a valid certificate and HOST file changes.